# How to replace the content on my asp.net page at the drop down selection

Tags: c#, forms, drop-down-menu

There are 2 types of users for my page.
1. visitor
2. Registered Member.

Login form for these two are different.
How do I present two forms. I think a drop down selection for member/visitor might work. But How?
I am new to programming. Please help.
If I disable the unnecessary controls for visitor, after drop down selection. then place it takes is much.
i just want to replace the whole form with new one.. on drop down selection. is that possible on the same page. Without navigating. and how?

Comment: If you want to keep the space then you may want to look into jquery. This is perhaps a bit advanced, however this will allow you to create collapsible list items. So I would put the two login's in a different list item, then collapse one from whatever the drop down selection is.

Comment: This link maybe useful to see what jquery can do to help space issues: http://www.sendesignz.com/index.php/jquery/77-how-to-create-expand-and-collapse-list-item-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to place content of page in two different panels.

On changing index of dropdown you will have to set its visibility to true or false as you want according to content you want to show.

```
panel1.visible=true;
panel2.visible=false;
```

Comment: It should be noted that this won't help his problem with space issues. Will simply hide one from view but it would still be there.

Comment: will that panel be replaced or it will still take space but not appear?

Comment: Its bad English however: If I disable the unnecessary controls for visitor, after drop down selection. **then place it takes is much.**

Comment: nope, with panel, it will not consume any extra place. it will show it in front. i daily use this logic in my programs

Comment: @SyedSohailAhmed just use it, there will be no space issue...or just do small code snippet with panels with above logic

Comment: So you want to tell him how he can overlap the two panels in asp.net?

Comment: yup, i want to tell him that

Answer (score 0):

You can use Asp.net inbuilt login control. This provides you the flexibility to show the different stuff for anonymous and logged in user. For this there's a LoginView contorol available.

see the documentation : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)